# Word for a person who always looks as if they are smiling when in fact they are not happy

Tags: single-word-requests

I wonder if there is term for a person who seems as if they are smiling when in fact not actually in a happy mood.

There was a classmate of mine who  **never looked serious.** When he failed an exam, (though he was saying he was upset over that) **still** he looked like he had a slight smile.

Is there any term for the person  who regardless of any predicaments or failure, seems to be smiling?

Comment: Are you looking for the opposite of a resting bitch face? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resting_bitch_face

Comment: What if it is a woman that is smiling? There's probably a different word.

Comment: To @Mitch: Yes.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal I was kidding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, a [*resting nice face*](http://thelala.com/rbfs-lesser-known-alter-ego-resting-nice-face/) is a thing.

> But no one ever mentions resting bitch faces lesser-known opposite: resting nice face. In fact, you may have never even heard of it. ***Resting nice face*** is a having a consistently friendly face and for the few of us out there it leads to our own unique challenges.

It's the opposite of having a **[resting bitch face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resting_bitch_face)**.